# Erase part of RenderTarget when drawing primitives?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna

I'm creating a paint like application using XNA.

I have a render target which acts as a canvas. When the user draws something I draw corresponding triangles using `DrawUserPrimitives` and triangle strips to make lines and other curves.

I want to implement an eraser in the application, so that the user can erase the triangles from the texture. I've used OpenGL in the past and there I would just use a blend function like so:  `glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

How would I do this in XNA? I tried setting the `GraphicsDevice` blend mode to `AlphaBlend`, `Additive`, etc.. but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Erase the triangles? Or make some pixels of the render target transparent? The former doesn't really work with a render target.

Comment: I want to make the pixels of the render target transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to use a `Texture2D` instead of a `RenderTarget2D`, you can use `RenderTarget2D.GetTexture()` to get the pixel data from the `RenderTarget2D`.

Of course, there will probably be a performance hit, but if you can optimize the code in a way that cuts down on the number of times this is done, like temporarily drawing the background color instead of actually erasing, and then iterating through the pixels after the mouse is released, you could make it work.

There may be a better way, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I see. I would really like to avoid doing that as it would a bad performance hit In my case, even with the optimizations you suggested. Maybe there is a way to use blend modes or something to achieve this?